# How exactly do I install MongoDB 2.4, instead of the latest version?

Tags: mongodb

I've read the [instructions on installing older versions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) but it appears that 2.4 is no longer available in the repos?

```
aptitude -y install mongodb-org-server=2.4
Unable to find a version "2.4" for the package "mongodb-org-server"
Unable to find a version "2.4" for the package "mongodb-org-server"
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mongodb-org-server
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/9,416 kB of archives. After unpacking 23.7 MB will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package mongodb-org-server.
(Reading database ... 33931 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-server_2.6.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-server (2.6.3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Setting up mongodb-org-server (2.6.3) ...
mongod start/running, process 30690
```

UPDATE: I've also filed a [ticket with Mongo's JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-3751), which has received a reply.

Comment: You can download version 2.4:
http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/

Comment: The docs for 2.4 can be found at https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.4/ that's a good starting point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that starting with v2.6, Mongo is releasing packages that match the Ubuntu ones:

- mongodb-org - metapackage that will automatically install the four component packages listed below.
- mongodb-org-server - the mongod daemon and associated configuration and init scripts.
- mongodb-org-mongos - the mongos daemon.
- mongodb-org-shell - the mongo shell.
- mongodb-org-tools - mongoimport, mongorestore etc.

But up to v2.4, Mongo published a [mongodb-10gen package](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/), which apparently is what you need to install:

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen=2.4.10
```

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package mongodb-10gen` :(

Answer (score 2):

This is probably already solved, but the documentation shows [how to install mongoDB 2.4](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.4/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/):

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen=2.4.14`

Answer (score 1):

@SSH This
Mongodb 2.4.13 is absolete and the only way you will be able to install it is to download rpms

```
wget http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64/RPMS/mongo-10gen-server-2.4.13-mongodb_1.x86_64.rpm
wget http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64/RPMS/mongo-10gen-2.4.13-mongodb_1.x86_64.rpm
```

and install them. That's for redhat/fedora/centos and alike. For ubuntu, you'll need the ubuntu packages.